# Keep track of all objects created using a form

Tags: django, forms, primary-key, field

Ok, this might take a bit of explanation.

I have a class called `PurchaceOrder`, which has a form with 18 fields. A lot of the time, there will be several `PurchaceOrders` with the first 12 fields being the same. To facilitate this (and remove the chance of a user making an error when trying to make the 12 fields the same every time) I have a form that allows the user to add more than one `PurchaceOrder` with the first 12 Fields being carried over from one entry to the next. This is all fine and good, and is working very well.

However; I need a splash page after the user is done adding all of his/her `PurchaceOrders`, that shows all the entries that were just made. This means I need to track the new entries that are being created,  but I can't think of a way to do this. For now I'm just filtering the categories, so that the `PurchaceOrders` with the first 12 fields being the same as the ones just entered are displayed, but this obviously won't really work (there could be a previous entry that has those 12 fields that are the same). What I'd really like to have is a list of Primary Keys of the entries that were just created. I could then pass this information onto the view that's responsible for the confirmation landing page.

In my current view I have the following:

```
 if form.is_valid():
    entry=form.save()
```

My thinking was that I could then do something like:

```
pks = [pks, entry.id]
```

I don't know where I would instantiate the list. If I did it in the view, it would be whipped out every time the page was reloaded.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving this alone for a long time, I've finally come up with a suitable solution. What I've done is created a url conf that has a regex of `(?P<match>/+)/`in it. That rexeg will be used to contain an arbitrary number of primary keys separated by `/`. I use this to store all of the primary keys of the `PurchaseOrders` that have been created (that is, when I create `PurchaseOrder` number 15, it redirects me to `/new/15`, then when I create number 16, it directs me to `/new/15/16/`, and so on. Then when I'm ready to confirm, I'm sent to `/confirm/15/16/` and I can easily access the pk's of the entries I've just created by calling  `pks=match.split('/')`. I can then simply iterate through `pks` and do something for each object. I think it's an elegant solution, as long as you don't mind your user seeing the primary keys in the url.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to have a separate class/method/function that keeps track of the PurchaceOrder's in each form.  The ID could be tied to the result through a database or array/linked list that is auto-incremented when a new PurchaceOrder is created.

As far as instantiating the list, have it instantiated when the class is first called, or have it as a separate class.  After writing that, a separate class makes more sense, which is probably why I posted it that way originally.

Comment: That just seems way more complicated than it needs to be. It should be relatively simple to just store a list of integers--it shouldn't need that much built around it. As far as I can tell, your suggestion would require two classes--one class (called something like `PK`) that just has an IntegerField, and another class (called something like `PKList`) that has a ManyToManyField, which can hold many PKs. But this all feels like too much work for just a list of integers. Hm...